# I want to modify a sample from the http://developer.android.com/, but have some problems with Cyrillic symbols

Tags: android, character-encoding, internationalization

First, sorry for my poor language skills.

I tried to modify the SearchableDictionary v2 sample from here: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html
I need this for a school project.

I replaced the definitions in dev/raw/definitons.txt with some other definitions, which was written in Cyrillic, but now when I run the project and search for a word it doesn't show me word I was searching for.

However, if I enter some words in Latin symbols in definitions.txt, then the app works great, but when I put some words in Cyrillic it doesn't show me the words, when I search for them.

I assume that this is due to some encoding issues?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to encoding. In Eclipse, right click on the definitions.txt file and select properties. There you should see an option to specify the charset. Make sure its set to whatever you need (probably UTF-8)